# SQL SERVER Which Query is faster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Which query is faster:

**Query A**

```
SELECT I.ItemName
FROM Location L
INNER JOIN Items I ON I.LocationID = L.LocationID
WHERE L.LocationID = 1
```

Execution Plan
[image]

**Query B**

```
SELECT ItemName
FROM Items 
WHERE ItemID IN (
SELECT ItemID
FROM  Items
WHERE LocationID = 1)
```

Execution Plan
[image]

Comment: I had poor performance for a. Now I changed it to b but want to confirm will it work for me

Comment: Those execution plans look identical to me, meaning that you will see identical performance for those two plans. If you execute those queries again, with the plans you posted, do you see the same performance? If not, can you post the execution plans on pastetheplan.com (instead of images)?

Comment: Side note, but very important, execution plans are not a measure of performance, ever. They are simply a description of what was done to satisfy the query. To measure performance you need to use something like Extended Events, Query Store, or the DMVs.

Comment: The queries you post in the question aren't the same. The first one connects the tables via a common `LocationID` and the second one via a common `ItemID`

Comment: What Martin said above. Also the second query accesses only table `Items` - unless it's a typo and the subquery is supposed to access `Locations`.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand the question. Which are you observing as running faster? This is good information to diagnose an issue, but the actual results are always more accurate and useful.

Answer (score 12):

Neither. Try:

```
SELECT I.ItemName
FROM Items I
WHERE I.LocationID = 1
```

...and add a [covering index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-ver15#to-create-an-index-with-nonkey-columns-1) on `LocationID` with INCLUDE column `ItemName`  .

Answer (score 0):

Your table is stored in heap.
This means it is unsorted in any way.

Please consider to add a clustered Index or primary key, so sqlserver can go and find the data you need without reading every byte.

Once, your data is clustered, you can use

```
SELECT ItemName
FROM Items
WHERE LocationId = 1
```

and maybe add an index on 'LocationID' and include 'ItemName'.

[about 'RID Lookup'](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/39281/what-is-a-rid-lookup.html)